# Response from dataBase is null PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I am very new in PHP and I'm trying to connect to my mysql database.
The code for select is the following:

```
public function getAllTeams(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM maras_app");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    echo json_encode($result);
    return $result;
}
```

The connection is successful because I put in code to echo if there is an error. The response I get is the following:

```
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

The tables have 14 columns. 
In the dataBase I have only one row inserted with last 4 columns null.
Any idea why I'm getting null as response?

This is how I'm creating my connection:

```
private $conn;

    //Constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Configuratii.php';
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/ConexiunDB.php';
        // opening db connection
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }
```

Here is Configuratii.php:

```
define('DB_USERNAME', '---');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '---');
define('DB_HOST', '---');
define('DB_NAME', '---');
```

And here is ConexiunDB.php:

```
 class DbConnect
{

private $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
    }
    function connect()
    {
        require_once 'Configuratii.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
            $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    // Check for database connection error
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

    // returing connection resource
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }
```

I really can't get what's there and don't know to debug because is the second time I use PHP.

Comment: Recommend you change your DB credentials ASAP, as you have just posted them publicly on the internet. I edited them out of your question, but you should really change it right away.

Comment: thanks a lot! I always forget doing that...

Comment: You need to call something like `->fetch_array()` to get the data.

Comment: Please post an answer with the `getAllTeams()` code changes to allow the question to be closed.